# SQLite CREATE TABLE AS but rename columns and keep original data types, keys?

Tags: sql, sqlite

**SQLite Objective**

I would like to create a new table from a join (or series of joins/subqueries). I would like the new table to preserve the data types in the original tables as well as the unique index.

In addition, I would like to rename some of the columns in the process. To do this in SQLite, I am under the impression that I need to do the following steps:

> 1. Create the joined table as a temporary table
> 2. Create an empty new table with the desired column names, data types, and index
> 3. Insert the temporary table into the new table.

**Question: Is there a better or more succinct way to accomplish this task?**

*Code example of above process:*

```sql
--create joined table as tmp
DROP TABLE if exists tmp;

CREATE TABLE tmp AS
SELECT 
    individual_contributions.cmte_id, 
    cmte_pty_affiliation, 
    name, 
    employer, 
    transaction_dt,
    transaction_amt,
    file_num,
    cand_id,
    sub_id 
    FROM individual_contributions LEFT JOIN committee_master 
    ON individual_contributions.cmte_id=committee_master.cmte_id
    WHERE employer LIKE "Goldman Sachs"
    GROUP BY sub_id;
```

```sql
--create new table with desired specs
DROP TABLE if exists cm_indiv;

CREATE TABLE cm_indiv (
    cmte_id TEXT NOT NULL,
    cmte_pty_affiliation TEXT,
    contributor_name TEXT,
    contributor_employer TEXT,
    contributor_transaction_dt TEXT,
    cand_id TEXT,
    transaction_amt TEXT,
    file_num NUMERIC,
    sub_id NUMERIC NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_cm_indiv ON cm_indiv (sub_id);
```

```sql
--insert joined table into new table
INSERT INTO cm_indiv (
    cmte_id,
    cmte_pty_affiliation,
    contributor_name,
    contributor_employer,
    contributor_transaction_dt,
    cand_id,
    transaction_amt,
    file_num,
    sub_id
    )
SELECT 
    cmte_id,
    cmte_pty_affiliation,
    name,
    employer,
    transaction_dt,
    cand_id,
    transaction_amt,
    file_num,
    sub_id
    FROM tmp;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This CTAS works for me using SQL Fiddle (SQLite-WebSQL). Therefore when you create the table, use the preferred column name in the select statement like below.

```
create table tbl( id int);

insert into tbl values (1);

create table new_tbl 
as 
select id as new_id 
from tbl;

select new_id from new_tbl;

Result: 
new_id
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the new table first, then insert the joined data directly:

```
CREATE TABLE cm_indiv ( cmte_id TEXT NOT NULL, ...);

INSERT INTO cm_indiv(...) SELECT ... FROM ... JOIN ...;

CREATE INDEX ...;
```